# Quickbuild only runs PdfLaTeX

Tags: texmaker

If I manually run PDFLaTeX - BibTeX - PDFLaTeX - PDFLaTeX - View PDF, it all works as intended. Options-->configure-->quick build is changed to this sequence, but it never happens. If I press quick build, it will only run PDFLaTeX once, then I manually need to run bibt, 2xpdft and view pdf afterwards. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 on windows, with Texmaker.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) that is standard in TeXMaker, quick build runs pdflatex once and trickers a refresh in the PDF viewer. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I don't use quiclatex but I think Quickbuild is only `PDFLaTeX - View PDF`. That's why it is quick

Comment: @daleif Roger states that he has changed the QuickBuild-settings to run the mentioned sequence, but that it doesn't work.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes, but I still does not understand what the OP is asking for

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of our configuration for the quickbuild command? How are you using the quickbuild? Pressing a key or clicking on the button?

Comment: [Screenshot](https://postimg.org/image/trtr6we07/) of my quickbuild settings in Texmaker. When executing I press the rightarrow on the left from the drop-down menu where it says 'Quick Build'. As stated, after this I need to scroll down in the drop-down menu, choose BibTeX, execute that, change back (or to PdfLaTeX), execute, and then run View PDF. If I do this it all works, no BibTeX errors.

Comment: And as I tried to explain in the first post, the Pdf is never previewed  after pressing 'Quick Build' either.